# Error while creating a table from c#

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql, postgresql-9.6

I am trying to create table using `Npgsql` and `command.Parameters.AddWithValue` function. Here is the following code:

Attempt 1:

```
string databaseName = "MyDatabase";
using (NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(" CREATE DATABASE :DBNAME ", conn))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(":DBNAME", "'" + databaseName + "'");
    await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
}
```

Attempt 2:

```
string databaseName = "MyDatabase";
using (NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(" CREATE DATABASE :DBNAME ", conn))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(":DBNAME", "\"" + databaseName + "\"");
    await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
}
```

Attempt 3

```
string databaseName = "MyDatabase";
using (NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(" CREATE DATABASE :DBNAME ", conn))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(":DBNAME", databaseName);
    await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
}
```

I am unable to execute this code because of `syntax error at or near "$1"` error. What am I doing wrong? I have used this syntax for select queries and there was no problem, f.e.:

```
using (NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(" SELECT * FROM \"Students\" WHERE \"Id\" = :Id ", conn))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(":Id", 1);
    int id = (int)await command.ExecuteScalarAsync();
}
```

and this query works perfectly. What is the difference?

EDIT: How can I create databases and tables preventing SQL injection? Is following statement safe? `format('CREATE DATABASE %1$s', 'MyDatabase')`

Comment: 1. Table != Database 2. You cannot parametrize table name. You need to use string concatenation/substitution (possible SQL Injection)

Comment: In my app users can create their own tables. I was always hear that all parameters cannot be concatenating directly, it need to be passed by parameter array because of security reasons

Comment: You cannot have an object name like a database name as parameter to a statement. You'll have to use dynamic SQL. Use the `format()` function with the `%I` pattern to avoid SQL injection. An application that creates database on the fly is badly designed in my opinion.

Comment: As explained by @lad2025 you cannot use a parameter to represent a database/table/column name. If you allow your users to decide what is the table name then you need a lot of checking on the inputs received

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe You mean postgres builtin format function? For example format('CREATE DATABASE %1$s', 'MyDatabase')?

Comment: @AdamMrozek Precisely. Except that it would be `format('CREATE DATABASE %I', 'MyDatabase')` If you can, keep your names all lower case letters and digits.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Is this approach guarantee that no sql injection will be executed?

Comment: Yes. `format()` is safe as long as you use the `%I` and `%L` patterns. Only with `%s` you can add something unsafe.